# Showing Graphs in Mosync Mobile applications through HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, d3.js, charts

I'm working on a cross-platform mobile application through MoSync.I need to show charts in Web view .i have done this in netbeans usin D3 JS in Which i'm using JSON data. i'm run the Application on server and the output shown in Browser; i need the same output on MoSync App. I dont know how to Achive this plz Help!